# In my code, only one link is parse, but I have four different links. How can I parse all of them

Tags: android, json

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Button btn;
TextView price;

String url = "https://koinim.com/ticker/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get_information);
    price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override

public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_get_information){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new
                JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            price.setText("BTC: " +
                                    response.getString("sell")+ " " + "₺" );

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext()),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                }

                });

                        MySingleton.getmInstance(getApplicationContext()).
                                addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

}

I am a new developer in android.
I looked at the sources and made the parse from one link. But I have four links. How do I parse the four links?

Comment: What links do you mean?

Comment: sorry 
I wanted to say url

Comment: So you want to parse 4 urls with one button-click?

Comment: Yeah. if something like that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a String url, create an ArrayList of Strings that holds all your URLs.

In the method onClick() loop through the URLs.

Note that the ArrayList is filled in onCreate. I also added a try/catch clause in onClick, so if something goes wrong with one URL, the others will be parsed anyways.

**Handling different URLs:**

For parsing the Koinim ticker, you needed the key "sell", for Paribu you will need "last".

In the loop I am checking if the URL contains either Koinim or Paribu and adjust they key accordingly.

```
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_information);
        price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

        urls.add("https://koinim.com/ticker/");
        urls.add("url2");
        urls.add("url3");
        urls.add("url4");

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_get_information) {

            for (String url : urls) {
                try {
                    JsonObjectRequest request = null;

                    if(url.contains("koinim"))
                    {
                        request = getSellPrice("sell");
                    }
                    else if(url.contains("paribu"))
                    {
                        request = getSellPrice("last");
                    }

                    if(request != null)
                    {
                        MySingleton.getmInstance(getApplicationContext()).
                                addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // something went wrong, handle exception here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private JsonObjectRequest getSellPrice(String key)
    {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new
                JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            price.setText("BTC: " +
                                    response.getString(key) + " " + "₺");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext()), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                    }

                });

        return jsonObjectRequest;
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please set my answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: but 
I have one more question.

Comment: I guess this url can not be parsed because the json structure is different. how do i add this to the code.      https://www.paribu.com/ticker

Comment: I've updated my answer one more time. Please note that I didn't test it, but I think you get the concept.